# MongoError: server instance in invalid state undefined after upgrading mongoose module

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I updated my `mongoose` npm module from  `"mongoose": "~3.8.8"` to `"mongoose": "^4.1.12"`. I am using simple MEAN project as is [documented here](http://meanjs.org/docs/0.3.x/) and got following error after upgrading `mongoose` node module :

```
MongoError: server instance in invalid state undefined
    at Function.MongoError.create (SampleProject\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
    at Server.connect (SampleProject\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:341:22)
    at Server.connect (SampleProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:357:17)
    at open (SampleProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:222:19)
    at Db.open (SampleProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:245:44)
    at MongoStore._open_database (SampleProject\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:182:15)
    at MongoStore._get_collection (SampleProject\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:177:14)
    at MongoStore.get (SampleProject\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:222:10)
    at Layer.session [as handle] (SampleProject\node_modules\express-session\index.js:204:11)
    at trim_prefix (SampleProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:230:15)
    at SampleProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:198:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (SampleProject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:253:12)
```

Any help ?

Comment: Same for me after upgrading Mongoose to 4.7.0

Comment: @jmcollin92 any luck ?

Comment: Yes. My MongoDB instance was simply not reachable (Mongod listen to 127.0.0.1 and not to 0.0.0.0). So the connect was blocking and subsequent calls to Mongoose fails with this error. The error is not very clear but the case is identified.

Comment: @jmcollin92 can you post it an answer with steps to rectify the problem. Please it would help others including myself.

Comment: Yes sure. Open your /etc/mongod.conf file, and change the line with : bindIp: 127.0.0.1 to bindIp: 0.0.0.0. Then restart MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution of my case.
This error occurs when Mongoose connection is started and you try to access database before the connection is finished.

In my case, my MongoDB is running in a Docker Container which exposes the 27017 port.
To be able to expose the port outside the Container, the mongod process inside Container must listen to 0.0.0.0 and not only 127.0.0.1 (which is the default).
So, the connect instruction hangs and program try to access collections before it ends.
To fix it, simply change the /etc/mongod.conf file and change `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` to `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`

I guess the error should be more comprehensive for human being... Something like "connection started but not finished" will be better for our understanding.